# How do I manually merge a branch in git?

Tags: git, github, git-merge

I merged a relatively old branch into master and the outcome of the merge was an unholy mess. For some unknown reason when I ran git merge it automatically took some of the out of date code that had since been updated in another branch and merged into master.

This old branch has only a few changes that I want and so doing something like

```
git difftool oldbranch
```

and manually copying over the changes with a visual difftool is a lot easier than cleaning up the mess caused by the automatic merge.

The problem with that approach is that it messes up my history/network/tree because it doesn't show that the branch is merged.

The question is how do I manually merge a branch in git without relying on the automatic merge (preferably with a graphical diff/merge tool)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This old branch has only a few changes that I want and so doing something like
>
> `git difftool oldbranch`
>
> and manually copying over the changes with a visual difftool is a lot easier than cleaning up the mess caused by the automatic merge.

Since this branch is old and only has a few changes that you want, what you could do instead is trying rebasing the changes onto `master`, then merge in the updated branch that way.

However, since you mentioned that the old branch somehow is also bringing in old changes that you don't want, let's be a little more selective on what you rebase.

Let's assume that all of the changes you actually do want are in atomic commits at the tip of your old branch, which we'll call branch `old`.  So the history for `old` will look a little something like this:

```
I         J          master
o---------o----------o
           \
            \
             o K
              \
               \
                o L
                 \
                  \
                   o old
```

Let's say that you want to merge commits `L` through `old` into `master`, but somehow `J` is a bad commit that's already been corrected in `master` but is somehow still being merged when you run

```bash
# With master checked out
git merge old
```

Let's also assume that `K` is also a "bad" commit that you don't want to add to `master`.

Then what you can do is make a new branch off the current commit of `master`, and selectively rebase commits `L` through `old` onto the new branch:

```bash
# Make a new branch off current commit of master
git branch new-branch master

# Now rebase L through old onto new-branch
git rebase --onto new-branch K old
```

What this tells Git is to take the commits between `K` and `old`, and copy them with different shas onto the tip of `new-branch`, leaving out `K` because it's the exclusive end of the range (in terms of number lines, that would be analogous to `(K, old]`).

So now your branches look like this:

```
I         J          master
o---------o----------o
           \          \
            \          \
             o K        o L`
              \          \
               \          \
                o L        o new-branch (same commit as where old branch was at)
                 \
                  \
                   o old
```

Now you can merge in new-branch using either a fast-forward or non-fast-forward merge:

```bash
# From master branch, use fast-forward merge
git merge new-branch

# Or force a merge-commit with non-fast-forward
git merge --no-ff new-branch
```

Instead of using rebase, you could also be extremely selective with the commits you add to `new-branch` by using `cherry-pick` instead, which will let you select both a range of commits, as well as just single commits, thereby giving you more granular control.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to go this way, you can merge manually, and then use

```
git merge -s ours oldbranch
```

which will mark the branch as merged, but not apply any change to master.